# How to construct a database diagram using phpmyadmin?

Tags: php

hi everyone i have a question. there is a database in phpmyadmin that include a lot of tables which are connected to everyone almost. is there some mean so that i can have the diagram of all of the tables which are connected to each other

Thnx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to each other?" It's the queries you write that determine what tables connect to which.

Comment: @ATaylor That's not really true. When the tables are linked with `primary` and `foreign` keys, then it's possible to find out what table has a relation with another table etc. Thus you could make a database diagram from that. No idea if phpMyAdmin supports that though.

Comment: is phpmyadmin support this type of diagrams

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this in phpmyadmin... You need to use some external tool.

Try:

**MySQL Workbench:**
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

- When you choose your OS and download type mysql site will take you to one page where it asks you to login/register this is not required, there is link beneath that it says "» No thanks, just start my download!"

Export your database (structure only export) and use "Reverse Engineer Database" mode.

Comment: only as a comment, it was possible to do so in old versions of phpnmyadmin.